# Does GCP have a concept of Account Layering?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

With AWS when configuring an Enterprise deployment you'd typically have multiple tiers of accounts and then use IAM to manage the permissions for the various users/groups/roles across the accounts.

e.g.

```
Master Account (never used, password locked in a safe somewhere)
|- Finance Account
|- IAM Management Account
     |- Platform Tooling Account
         |- Dev Env Account
         |- Test Env Account
         |- Prod Env Account
```

I had a quick search around SO but didnt see any other questions that were similar (I search for 'account layering' and 'nested accounts' inside the google-cloud-platform tag).

Does GCP have a similar paradigm for account layering?

Answer (score 0):

With Google Cloud Platform, you have the notion of resource hierarchy:

[image]

IAM policies are hierarchical and propagate down the structure. The effective policy for a resource is the union of the policy set at that resource and the policy inherited from its parent.

[Google IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control)

Comment: That's the same as AWS IAM which is fine for granular control however misses one thing, if that master login gets exploited then it is game over for the entire account. With the layered accounts if, say, your dev account gets compromised then you only lose all of your development projects, servers, bucket data, etc if someone goes on a rampage deleting everything or worse (closing the account). Your master account is still shielded from this and your whole environment doesnt come down like a deck of cards. You'd still need another account to backup to otherwise you are really rolling the dice.

Comment: @madnazz understood. there is no "cross-account" IAM with Google Cloud Platform yet, but you can however protect your account with MFA (2SV) and even ip range (if on Google Apps for Business).